# Routing all ethernet connection requests to a single page

Tags: raspberry-pi, gateway, authorization

For an art exhibition, i am trying to configure a raspberry pi to work as a gateway to the internet. Connected to the pi is a 4G dongle and a wifi router. I have used IP Tables to forward all ethernet requests from the wifi router to the 4G dongle.

However I want newly connected users to view a single website before being allowed on the internet.

I think there might be a proxy of sorts that will be able to something like this but I haven't found it yet.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Research ["_Captive Portal_" implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal#Implementation). This is nothing to do with Ethernet, but more about directing clients to a login page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution that you need is a captive portal.

A Captive Portal is a webpage that will be shown initially to anyone who connects to your network.

In your Raspberry Pi you will need to install a captive portal software as [nodogsplash](https://github.com/nodogsplash/nodogsplash).